# HTML not displaying anything after a certain point in my JS file?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
console.log("Hi World!");
document.write("hi <br />");
var str = "string type";
var intType = 0;
var boolType = true;
var arrayType = [];
var objectType = {};
arrayType = [1, 2, 3];
var arrayNote = new Array(1, 2, 3);
document.write(arrayType[0] + '<br />');
var arraySparsed = new Array();
arraySparsed[5] = "defined";
document.write(arraySparsed + '<br />');
arrayType = [str, intType, boolType];
document.write(arrayType + '<br />');
var myStack = [];
myStack.push(str);
myStack.push(intType);
myStack.push(boolType);
document.write("my current stack: " + myStack + '<br />')
document.write("Pop element: " + myStack.pop() + '<br />')
document.write("my current stack after pop: " + myStack + '<br />')
document.write("Stack before shift: " + myStack + '<br />');
document.write("shifted: " + myStack.shift() + '<br />')
document.write("my stack now: " + myStack + '<br />');
document.write("Using unshift to add cat to the stack " + '<br /');
myStack.unshift('cat')
document.write(myStack + '<br /');
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>JSDemo</title>
  <meta name="My attempt to learn JS in a day" content="My attempt.">
  <meta name="Ian Brown" content="SitePoint">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?v=1.0">

</head>

<body>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

In the above, I am able to run everything until after "Using unshift to add cat to the stack", or `myStack.unshift('cat') document.write(myStack+'<br /');`

Are there too many line breaks? Do I need to extend the page? Not sure what to do and would appreciate some help!

Comment: You are just not closing those last line-breaks correctly. it should be `<br />` not `<br /`

Comment: *facepalm* I’m tired. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ippi said, you wrote `'<br /'` instead of `'<br />'` in the last 2 `.write()`s.